# rotating a line on a graph to make it parallel to the origin

Tags: trigonometry

how do I calculate the angle from the origin required to make a line anywhere on the graph rotate so that it is parallel with the origin.  I understand how to calculate if the line intersects the xy origin but I do not understand if it only intersects one axis.

Comment: The origin is a single point. How does one calculate the angle between a line and a point?

Comment: I meant that the origin is the center of rotation and that the angle I need would be from that point to the line segment once the segment is parallel to either the x or y axis

Comment: The required rotation angle is the same no matter where the line is. The tangent of this angle is equal to the slope of the line. Note, though, that you can perform the rotation without explicitly computing this angle. The value of the line’s slope is enough.

Comment: thanks for your response amd.  This verified the simple solution that for some reason didn't make sense to me.